# How to send the last value of State as a property

Tags: reactjs, routes, use-state

I just learn react and this is the problem I haven't been able to figure out for hours.

I have the App component and I want to pass data about user login to the ProtectedRoute component so I can handle access to the admin page.

In the App there is a function which manages lifting data up from the Login component (based on Firebase user authentication).

The problem is, the userLogged state is set too late so Protected route receives default value of the state.

How can I send the last state to the ProtectedRoute component?

```
import {useState} from "react"
import './App.css'
import Login from "./components/admin/Login"
import Homepage from "./components/homepage/Homepage"
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute"
import AdminPage from "./components/admin/AdminPage"


function App() {
  
  const [userLogged, setUserLogged] = useState()

  const getUser = (data) => {
    setUserLogged(data)
    console.log("data: " + data)
    console.log("state: " + userLogged) 
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login sendUser={getUser}/>} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute isLoggedIn={userLogged} />}>
          <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App
```

This is the ProtectedRoute component, where I tried to add useEffect. It still doesn't work this way.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"

const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
    

const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLogged(props.isLoggedIn);
  console.log(isLogged);
}, [props.isLoggedIn]);

    return isLogged ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;

};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: you can use useEffect that will be trigger when your state will be updated.
or you can use setTimeOut  to give a bit of delay, something like 250 milisec

Comment: can you please provide the ProtectedRoute component to see how userLogged is being used there?

Comment: I have tried to use useEffect setTimeOut as well. None of that worked, maybe I just don't know where exactly use these functions. Also I have just updated the post with ProtectedRoute component. Thank you guys.